# create dummy request entity object to return while mocking testing request .post method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

i am trying to mock a request entity objcet for testing a *RequestEntity.post* method.

```
   RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> body = RequestEntity.post(new 
    URI(inquiryProperties.getEndCustomer()))

  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(customerInfo);
```

i want to mock this method using mockito and in "when " i want to return a dummy object for this.

this is my method i am trying to mock for the controller.

```
            private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InquiryController.class);

@Autowired
private InquiryProperties inquiryProperties;

@Autowired
private InquiryService inquiryService;


@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public static int count = 0;


@Bean
private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}





        public ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>> endCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerInfo customerInfo)
        throws IOException, JSONException {

    log.info("### InquiryController.endCustomer() ===>");
    List<EndCustomerDTO> endCustomerDTOs = null;

    try {

        //RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> body = RequestEntity.post(new URI(inquiryProperties.getEndCustomer()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(customerInfo);
        ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>> response = restTemplate.exchange(body,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<EndCustomerDTO>>() {
                });
        endCustomerDTOs = (response != null ? response.getBody() : new ArrayList<EndCustomerDTO>());

    } catch (RestClientException | URISyntaxException e) {
        log.error("InquiryController.endCustomer()" + e.getMessage());
    }

    log.info("### END InquiryController.endCustomer()  ===>");

    if (null == endCustomerDTOs) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>>(new ArrayList<EndCustomerDTO>(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>>(endCustomerDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear. What is the code you want to test, and what is the object and the method of that object that you want to mock?

Comment: i have added the full code

Comment: But you haven't answered my question.

Comment: i want to test the end cudtomer method, and for that i need to mock the request entity object and the response object @JB Nizet

Comment: No. The response object is what you need to test: does your method return the right response. What you need to mock is the restTemplate.exchange() method, or batter, the backend where the rest template sends its request. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template for the two choices explained with an example

Answer (score 0):

Sample with Mockito for mocking REST Template Exchange and Spying Response Entity

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomerTest {

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Spy
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    @Inject
    InquiryService inquiryService;

    @Test
    public void endCustomerTest() {
    EndCustomerDTO yourEndCustomerDTO= new EndCustomerDTO();
    //define the entity you want the exchange to return
    ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO >> yourEndCustomerDTOEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO >>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
        Matchers.eq("/urlPattern/urlPath"),
        Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
        Matchers.<HttpEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO >>>any(),
        Matchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<EndCustomerDTO >>>any())
    ).thenReturn(yourEndCustomerDTOEntity);
    //service call to get the end customers
    List<EndCustomerDTO > result = inquiryService.getEndCustomers();
    //asserting by comparing expected and actual value
    Assert.assertEquals(yourEndCustomerDTOEntity , result .get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what is "client".
and what would client.target mean?
and for the path do i need to enter the actual path?
and if the path is given , wouldn't it be called

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh HttpClient is an argument for creating HttpService. Path you can specify the mapped request path. Ideally it would be invoked. Are you trying for an API testing? If so the API should be hit or else we could Mock entire Request/Response.

Comment: i'm not doing it for api testing, can you further tell me the steps for mocking the request/response

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh 2 things. First, Here we are mocking only the Request and hitting API. We are comparing the Response with expected data. Second, Are you intending to mock both Request and Response ? If so there is no use of calling the API and requestEntity.post()

Comment: i have added the full code. as this code is not written by me, i cannot change the layout of the code. i have to write the test case for it using mockito

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh I have updated answer based on the updated question. Could you please take a look. Thank you

Comment: i tried this, but when i debug the code , it  gievs reflection error as soon as it enters the request entity part in the actual code, i guess that also has to be mocked

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh What is the exception you getting ?

Comment: as i debug the code. as soon as i enter the request entity part in actual code, it throws so reflection error. i guess * RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> body = RequestEntity.post(new URI(inquiryProperties.getEndCustomer()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(customerInfo);*
in this part. this also needs to be mocked i guess

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh Try Spy
    RequestEntity requestEntity= mock(RequestEntity.class)